# Write a program to decide if a number is prime

Tags: python, input, primes

I am trying to write a program which works with prime numbers.

A prime number is a number that is only evenly divisible by itself and 1. For example, the number 5 is prime because it can only be evenly divided by 1 and 5. The number 6, however, is not prime because it can be divided evenly by 1, 2, 3, and 6.

My task consists of:

- write a Boolean function `named is_prime()` which takes an integer as an argument and returns true if the argument is a prime number, or false otherwise.
- Use the function in a program that prompts the user to enter a number then displays a message indicating whether the number is prime.

```
def main():
    #decribe the program
    print ("This is a program to see if a number is prime")
    #ask the user for a number
    number = int (input ("Enter a number to see if it prime: "))
    #see if the number is prime
    result = is_prime (number)
    print ("The number", number, "is", result)

def is_prime(number): 
    while number < 0:
        print ("The number must be greater than 1")
        number = int (input("Enter a valid number: "))
    
    for x in range (1, number + 1):
        if (number % x) == 0:
            return False
        else: 
            return True
 
main()
```

In my for statement, I am missing something and having a hard time figuring out what I did wrong. What step am I missing?

Comment: `if number % x == 0` will return `True` immediately when `x == 1`.

Comment: It will also return `True` when `x == number` in the end (anyway, you only need to check for `x` no greater than `sqrt(number)`)

Answer (score 0):

The range of numbers checked inside `is_prime(number)` cannot include the numbers `(1, number)`, because any number is divisible by them. Additionally, you can only return `True` at the end of the `for-loop` if no divisors were found:

```
def is_prime(number): 
    ...

    for x in range (2, number):
        if (number % x) == 0:
            return False
     return True
```

---

For optimal execution speed, it can be proven that you only need to check numbers until `sqrt(number)`:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
def is_prime(number): 
    ...

    for x in range(2, min(number,1+ceil(sqrt(number)))):
        if (number % x) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the function `is_prime()`:

```
def is_prime(number): 
    while number < 1:
        print ("The number must be greater than 1")
        number = int (input("Enter a valid number: "))
    
    for x in range (2, number):
        if (number % x) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comments about my corrections:

- you have to exclude `1` and `number` so `range(2, number)` and not `range (1, number + 1)`
- `while number < 1:` better than `while number < 0:`
- At the end of the function you have to include the instruction `return True` because if the loop `for` reaches the end means that `number` is not divisible by any x value in interval [2,number). The `)` parenthesis means that x must be stops at `number-1`

Comment: very helpful! but why is it number - 1? we dont want to include the number?

Comment: Not because a number prime is divible by itself. So you have to stop before `number` at least at `number-1`. I have made a mistake `range` must be `range(2, number)` to exclude only `number`

Comment: @user1234Ep If this old answer was correct please accept it. This is normal here in StackOverflow and you can do it by clicking on the `V` simbol on the left-top of the answer. Thank you. This simple accept increase your reputation of 2 points, and mine of 15 points :)